# Perl latin-9? Unicode - need to add support

Tags: perl, unicode, character-encoding, latin9

I have an application that is being expanded to the UK and I will need to add support for Latin-9 Unicode. I have done some Googling but found nothing solid as to what is involved in the process. Any tips?

Here is some code (Just the bits for Unicode stuff)

```
use Unicode::String qw(utf8 latin1 utf16);

# How to call
$encoded_txt = $self->unicode_encode($item->{value});

# Function part
sub unicode_encode {

    shift() if ref($_[0]);
    my $toencode = shift();
    return undef unless defined($toencode);

    Unicode::String->stringify_as("utf8");
    my $unicode_str = Unicode::String->new();


    # encode Perl UTF-8 string into latin1 Unicode::String
    #  - currently only Basic Latin and Latin 1 Supplement
    #    are supported here due to issues with Unicode::String .
    $unicode_str->latin1( $toencode );
    ...
```

Any help would be great and thanks.

EDIT:
I did find this post: http://czyborra.com/charsets/iso8859.html

Comment: Why do you need to support Latin-9? Is there something specific in that format for data you'll be receiving? If it's certain characters that you need to support rather than a specific character set, I'd recommend going with full on Unicode and UTF-8.

Comment: Latin-9 is like Latin-1 with the euro symbol, it's a popular choice if you don't want or can't jump to Unicode.

Comment: Latin-9 is a business requirement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Unicode::String](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode::String) is ancient, and designed to add Unicode support to older Perls.  Modern versions of Perl (5.8.0 and up) have native Unicode support.  Look at the [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode) module and the [:encoding](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PerlIO::encoding) layer.  You can get a list of the supported encodings in your Perl with `perldoc Encode::Supported`.

Basically, you just need to decode/encode to Latin-9 on input & output.  The rest of the time, you should use Perl's native UTF-8 strings.

```
# Read a Latin-9 file:
open(my $in, '<:encoding(Latin9)', 'some/file');
my $line = <$in>; # Automatically converts Latin9 to UTF-8

# Write a Latin-9 file:
open(my $out, '>:encoding(Latin9)', 'other/file');
print $out $line; # Automatically converts UTF-8 to Latin9
```

Comment: Thanks, I did look at the reference you gave but I didn't see Latin-9. Any other references/advice?

Comment: Thanks again, I do have one other issue as some of the client running the old software might not be able to upgrade to a new version of Perl. Is there any support for Latin-9 using the Unicode::String way instead of :encoding? Just want to make it as easy for clients to upgrade as possible.

Comment: Try `perldoc Encode::Supported` to get a list of supported encodings.  search.cpan.org doesn't seem to find the current version (because it got moved to a different place in the tarball).

Comment: Perl 5.6.1 is 9 years old now.  (Even 5.6.2 is almost 7.)  It's time for them to upgrade.  I doubt it would be hard to add Latin9 support to Unicode::String, but you'd probably have to do it yourself.

Comment: hmm trying to use encode for this and it's not working. UK € Code: encode("iso-8859-15", "UK €") any thoughts as to why?

Answer (score 0):

In perldoc Encode::Supported it's referred to as ISO-8859-15 (!).  Here is some heavily trimmed down output from perldoc:

```
           Lang/Regions  ISO/Other Std.  DOS     Windows Macintosh  Others
       ----------------------------------------------------------------
       Latin9 [4]    iso-8859-15
       ----------------------------------------------------------------

       [4] Nicknamed Latin0; the Euro sign as well as French and Finnish
           letters that are missing from 8859-1 were added.
```