# Perl - Unicode::String sub need to add/convert for Latin-9 support

Tags: perl, unicode, encode

Part 3 ([Part 2 is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046595/perl-encode-uk-characters)) ([Part 1 is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039600/perl-latin-9-unicode-need-to-add-support))

Here is the perl Mod I'm using: [Unicode::String](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Unicode-String-2.09/String.pm)

How I'm calling it:

```
print "Euro: ";
print unicode_encode("€")."\n";
print "Pound: ";
print unicode_encode("£")."\n";
```

would like it to return this format:

```
&#x20AC; # Euro
&#x00A3; # Pound
```

The function is below:

```
sub unicode_encode {

    shift() if ref( $_[0] );
    my $toencode = shift();
    return undef unless defined($toencode);

    print "Passed: ".$toencode."\n";

    Unicode::String->stringify_as("utf8");
    my $unicode_str = Unicode::String->new();
    my $text_str    = "";
    my $pack_str    = "";

    # encode Perl UTF-8 string into latin1 Unicode::String
    #  - currently only Basic Latin and Latin 1 Supplement
    #    are supported here due to issues with Unicode::String .
    $unicode_str->latin1($toencode);

    print "Latin 1: ".$unicode_str."\n";

    # Convert to hex format ("U+XXXX U+XXXX ")
    $text_str = $unicode_str->hex;

    # Now, the interesting part.
    # We must search for the (now hex-encoded)
    #       Unicode escape sequence.
    my $pattern =
'U\+005[C|c] U\+0058 U\+00([0-9A-Fa-f])([0-9A-Fa-f]) U\+00([0-9A-Fa-f])([0-9A-Fa-f]) U\+00([0-9A-Fa-f])([0-9A-Fa-f]) U\+00([0-9A-Fa-f])([0-9A-Fa-f])';

    # Replace escapes with entities (beginning of string)
    $_ = $text_str;
    if (/^$pattern/) {
        $pack_str = pack "H8", "$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8";
        $text_str =~ s/^$pattern/\&#x$pack_str/;
    }

    # Replace escapes with entities (middle of string)
    $_ = $text_str;
    while (/ $pattern/) {
        $pack_str = pack "H8", "$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8";
        $text_str =~ s/ $pattern/\;\&#x$pack_str/;
        $_ = $text_str;
    }

    # Replace "U+"  with "&#x"      (beginning of string)
    $text_str =~ s/^U\+/&#x/;

    # Replace " U+" with ";&#x"     (middle of string)
    $text_str =~ s/ U\+/;&#x/g;

    # Append ";" to end of string to close last entity.
    # This last ";" at the end of the string isn't necessary in most parsers.
    # However, it is included anyways to ensure full compatibility.
    if ( $text_str ne "" ) {
        $text_str .= ';';
    }

    return $text_str;
}
```

I need to get the same output but need to Support Latin-9 characters as well, but the Unicode::String is limited to latin1. any thoughts on how I can get around this?

I have a couple of other questions and think I have a somewhat understanding of Unicode and Encodings but having time issues as well.

Thanks to anyone who helps me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have been told already, Unicode::String is not an appropriate choice of module.  Perl ships with a module called 'Encode' which can do everything you need.

If you have a character string in Perl like this:

```
my $euro = "\x{20ac}";
```

You can convert it to a string of bytes in Latin-9 like this:

```
my $bytes = encode("iso8859-15", $euro);
```

The `$bytes` variable will now contain \xA4.

Or you can have Perl automatically convert it out output to a filehandle like this:

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding(iso8859-15)");
```

You can refer to the documentation for the [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode) module.  And also, [PerlIO](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PerlIO) describes the encoding layer.

I know you are determined to ignore this final piece of advice but I'll offer it one last time.  Latin-9 is a legacy encoding.  Perl can quite happily read Latin-9 data and convert it to UTF-8 on the fly (using binmode).  You should not be writing more software that generates Latin-9 data you should be migrating away from it.

Comment: mclean, thnx again for your input on Latin-9 being legacy as well as Unicode::String. but as my job has required me to use Latin-9 in this project. Looking over the code they have provided me they are also using Unicode::String perl module. I also understand how optimal it would be to use the new encode() and remove the Unicode::String, but as project requirements don't allow me to do this I'm stuck with it. What I was trying to do (that doesn't work) is use the encode() instead of the latin1() in the sub but I wasn't having any luck. Thanks again for you advice and knowledge gained